# awk printing nothing when used in loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk, slurm

I have a bunch of files using the format file.1.a.1.txt that look like this:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
```

and was using the following command to add a new column containing the name of each file:

```
awk '{print FILENAME (NF?"\t":"") $0}' file.1.a.1.txt > file.1.a.1.txt
```

which ended up making them look how I want:

```
file.1.a.1.txt A 1
file.1.a.1.txt B 2
file.1.a.1.txt C 3
file.1.a.1.txt D 4
```

However, I need to do this for multiple files as a job on an HPC using sbatch submission. But when I run the following job script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#<other SBATCH info>
#SBATCH --array=1-10

N=$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

for j in {a,b,c};
do
    for i in {1,2,3}
    do awk '{print FILENAME (NF?"\t":"") $0}' file.${N}."$j"."$i".txt > file.${N}."$j"."$i".txt
    done
done
```

awk is generating empty files. I have tried using cat to call the file and then piping it to awk but that also hasn't worked.

Comment: Change `file.1.a.1.txt > file.1.a.1.txt` to `file.1.a.1.txt > temp && mv -f temp file.1.a.1.txt` -- you cannot redirect to the file being processed.

Comment: Welcome to SO, kudos for nice post(which has efforts in  form of code + sample of input  too), keep it up please. Could you please do let us know if we need to save output into Input_file itself? Also do all your file extensions are `.txt`?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 good comment, if all files can be identified by some glob, then there is no need for a loop -- which when you get the response would make a nice answer while also improving the efficiency of the task by 1000%+

Comment: Replace `> file.1.a.1.txt` with `| sponge > file.1.a.1.txt` if `sponge` is available.

Comment: Thanks, all file extensions are `.txt`. David's solution worked, though I am still not sure why the original formatting worked in the standalone and not in the job/loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop and you cannot redirect STDOUT to the same file you're reading from STDIN, you will get blank files if you do that.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

N=$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

awk '
   NF{
      print FILENAME "\t" $0 > FILENAME".tmp"
   }
   ENDFILE{ # requires gawk
      close(FILENAME".tmp") 
   }' file."$N".{a,b,c}.{1,2,3}.txt

for file in file*.tmp; do
   mv "$file" "${file%.tmp}"
done
```

Note that if you don't have GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to use `ENDFILE{}` you can remove that stanza and get away with either:

1. Putting the `close()` statement just after the `print` statement (comes with lots of overhead)
2. Don't call `close()` at all and as long as you don't have *a lot* of files, you should be fine.

Comment: This also worked for me, along with David R's suggestion of using `temp && mv -f temp`. I have ~1000 files with ~5M rows and only 2 columns; which solution would be best regarding runtime?

Comment: Well, you can find out by calling both scripts with the builtin `time` command in front of it.  As in `time /path/to/SiegeX/version.sh` and `time /path/to/your/modified/version.sh`.  I will say that I would be ***very*** surprised if mine wasn't faster because my version calls [tag:awk] ***one*** time, where as your version calls [tag:awk] once for ***each*** file it operates on.

Comment: P.S., if you update your question requirements to do what you want without a loop to maximize efficiency, this question will likely be re-opened for more answers.