# Redirection to file inside Bash loop + command works randomly

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Here's the self-explanatory one-liner I want to execute:

```
for f in *; do awk '{sub(FILENAME, FILENAME".")1}' $f > $f; done
```

This command does not work as wanted. The output files are all empty. I have searched the internet for the reason that happens, and it turns out loops in Bash are considered one single command, thus stream redirection is expected to be outside of it, after `"done"`

I then tried this, and the result is even more surprising:

```
for f in *; do awk '{sub(FILENAME, FILENAME".")1}' $f | tee $f; done
```

So now does not work too, except sometimes it does for one of the files in the directory, not the same. I copy over fresh copies of the files in the directory (that I have backed up somewhere else), I run that one-liner, and file B is modified as expected (others become empty). Then I recopy over fresh copies, rerun the command, then it's file C that gets modified as expected (others still empty). And some other times, it won't work for even one file.

1. Can you please tell me how I can achieve the desired result?
2. What is happening with that second command?

Comment: please describe in english what you're attempting to do for each file; what do you think `sub(FILENAME,FILENAME".")1` is supposed to do? both `$f > $f` and `$f | tee $f` are reading/writing-over the same file and as socowi's pointed out ... 'tis a recipe for disaster

Comment: The reason the files are empty is this: bash processes redirections **before** launching the command. The `>` redirection truncates the file to zero size **before** awk is invoked, and it has an empty file to read from.

Comment: See ["Why does `sort file > file` result in an empty file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841387/why-does-sort-file-file-result-in-an-empty-file), ["How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t), and ["awk printing nothing when used in loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62330138/awk-printing-nothing-when-used-in-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from a file while simultaneously overwriting it is a recipe for disaster. But with `cmd $f > $f` bash empties (= truncates) the file before `cmd` even runs. `cmd $f | tee $f` may work for short files because `cmd` and `tee` run in parallel and the output of `cmd` is buffered. If you are lucky, your system executes `cmd`'s read operations before `tee`'s truncate operation. The bigger the file, the less chance you have of reading *all* data before `tee` truncates it.

If you want to see this race condition between `cmd`'s read operation and `tee`'s truncate operation yourself, have a look at

```
head -c1M /dev/zero > f; LC_ALL=C strace -f -e execve,openat,read,write bash -c 'cat f | tee f' >/dev/null; wc -c f
```

My `tee` implementation from GNU coreutils 8.32 truncates the file by calling `openat(… "f" … O_TRUNC …)`. After that operation succeeded, `cat`'s next `read` will return `= 0`, signaling the end of file.

In your case, there are three possible solutions:

- Use a temporary file which you rename afterwards
  `awk ... "$f" > "$f.tmp"; mv "$f.tmp" "$f"`
- Use GNU awk's inplace option
  `gawk -i inplace ... "$f"`
- Use sponge from GNU moreutils
  `awk ... "$f" | sponge "$f"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's what I was looking for. But then, I understand why `tee` wouldn't work as expected, but can you please explain why the files are empty (most of the time) when using `tee`?

Comment: @user9128 I added more explanations. Whether or not the file is empty depends on how your system schedules the operations of programs running in parallel. `tee` is a simple program, so the operation that truncates the file comes very early; whereas `awk` does a lot of stuff before reading the file. Therefore, the chances of executing `awk`'s read before `tee`'s truncate are pretty slim. You can improve the chance by slowing `tee` down. `awk ... $f  | { sleep 1; tee $f; }` will give you a near 100% chance that `awk` reads at least one buffer of `$f`s content before `tee` truncates `$f`.